# How can adding new document.cookie in JS be done by the assignment (=) and not the addition assignment (+=) operator?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

The following command `console.log(typeof document.cookie);` prints `string` so it would be natural to think that adding new cookie should be done by incrementing this string's value, for instance:

```js
document.cookie += 'a=1;';
document.cookie += 'b=2;';
document.cookie += 'c=3;';
document.cookie += 'd=4;';
```

Then `console.log(document.cookie);` gives the following: `a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4`

However, this works as well (note the lack of plus signs and semicolons):

```js
document.cookie = 'a=1';
document.cookie = 'b=2';
document.cookie = 'c=3';
document.cookie = 'd=4';
```

`console.log(document.cookie);` still prints `a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4`

My question is - how is that possible? I don't assign this `document`'s property via a method, it's just a simple assignment. Is there any additional code in the browser engine that does the parsing? Are there any resources that could explain this behaviour?

Comment: Resources that explain this behavior: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-cookie and https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc6265.html#storage-model

Comment: The [`cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) property is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). If that answers your question, I can write it up as one. If not, what did I miss?

Comment: `My question is - how is that possible?` when you set a value, that value is parsed, meaning what you set as string is stored as key/value in a store (split by `=`), and what you get is then sent back as string by bulding the string with that key/value store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) property [`cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) is both a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), implemented as native code in the JS runtime.

In order to provide a visual and conceptual illustration, here is a **very** naïve implementation — this is not at all how it actually works, but perhaps it can help you understand how it's not just "a simple assignment":

```js
class Example {
  #cookie = {};

  get cookie() {
    return Object.entries(this.#cookie)
      .map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`)
      .join("; ");
  }

  set cookie(str) {
    const kv = this.#parse(str);
    if (kv) this.#cookie[kv[0]] = kv[1];
  }

  #parse(str) {
    const idx = str.indexOf("=");
    if (idx > 0) {
      const key = str.slice(0, idx);
      const value = str.slice(idx + 1);
      if (value.length > 0) return [key, value];
    }
  }
}

const doc = new Example();

console.log(doc.cookie); //=> ""

doc.cookie = "first=stack";
console.log(doc.cookie); //=> "first=stack"

doc.cookie = "second=overflow";
console.log(doc.cookie); //=> "first=stack; second=overflow"
```